# Cellpadding with spaces

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the space in each row? I've tried `padding: 0;` and it still won't work. But if I  click the toggle button, it shows no space. Look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/061oy8vb/)

Comment: which space u mean. between the checkboxes ?

Comment: the space between "Section 1" and "Section 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the table cell which are using `padding` but your checkboxes has margin on them on this rule of your `input[class="squaredTwo"]` so get rid of `margin: 20px auto;` or you can make it `margin: 5px auto;`

```
input[class="squaredTwo"] {
    /* Other declared properties */
    margin: 5px auto; /* Change here from 20 to 5 or whatever you like */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/061oy8vb/2/)

`margin: 5px auto;` is a shorthand property of `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` so when you write that it means `5px` for `margin-top` and `5px` for `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
input[class="squaredTwo"]{margin:0}
```